# Bundled product pricing/configuration confusion

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, bundled-product

It has been a while since I had the (dis)pleasure of working with bundled products in Magento but a current project we are working on, which has been migrated over from Opencart, is proving to be quite problematic with the default bundled product functionality.

All the products in the catalog had been imported over as simple products (many previous instances of failings when set up in Opencart). With quite a complex and in-depth catalog, we faced the task of converting products to configurable products and then selecting numerous other products as the associated products under the configurable (no problem with this).

Many other products contained optional extras which needed to be tied to actual physical products in the store (thus ruling out Magento's 'Custom Options). We decided to use 'Bundled Products' for this but upon converting the main product that contains said options to a bundled product and then adding the bundled items as the associated products, we discover that the default price just displays as the lowest price from the bundled items only.

I believe we need to have them set up as 'dynamic' pricing so that the prices change when different options (bundled items) are selected.

But whilst the bundled product is set to 'dynamic' pricing, we cannot see the base price (which would only appear if we changed to 'fixed' pricing.

Looking at [a demo bundled product in Magento 1.9.x](http://magento-demo.clubnetdev.com/mp3-player-with-audio.html), I can see that the main product is included as an option within the bundled product's associated products as per below:-

[image: Demo Bundled Product Front End]

[image: Demo Bundled Product Back End]

As per my above scenario, I haven't got the main product listed as a bundled item/associated product within the bundled product, it is in fact *the* actual product that I converted to a bundled product...

I am unsure how best to go about fixing this to be honest:-

- Should I be looking at coming up with a way of adding the main product to the bundled items even though it is the actual product that is the bundled product?
- Is there a way I can display fetch and display the original 'fixed' price as the base price for the bundled product? This would be a preferred option...

To help better explain, please view the below as a live example of the issue:-

[image: Bundled Product Pricing Issues]

Please excuse the styling but you will see that:-

- £36.00 is showing as the default ex VAT price.
- £43.20 is showing as the default inc VAT price.

Both of these are taken from the price of the bundled item, the checkbox you can see at the bottom of the image.

The actual price of the product is £3,196.00 (ex VAT) and £3,835.20 (inc VAT) which I need to be displaying as the default base price and then when the bundled item(s) are checked, the prices of these are then added on to the base default price.

The only way I can see to get the £3k prices to display is by setting the pricing to 'fixed' pricing but then we can't dynamically change the priced depending on the selected options.

Help! What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per my above scenario, I haven't got the main product listed as a bundled item/associated product within the bundled product, it is in fact the actual product that I converted to a bundled product...

And that's the problem. Think of bundle products as containers, that **don't have their own stock**. So if you care about stock management it's absolutely necessary to have the main product as simple product. Also it will solve your problem with price display as bundles with dynamic pricing don't have a base price, their price is the sum of all selected bundle options.

#### How to add a fixed main product to a bundle

1. Add one option, "main product" with type "checkbox" and make it "required".
2. Add the main product as only selection to this option, with "User defined qty" = "No".

The main product will show up on the bundle product page without input field or checkbox and its price will be shown for "price as configured" and "as low as"

Comment: That does indeed get it working as needed/intended, thank you for clarifying this. I just need to find a way of creating a duplicate bundle 'container' for every product that has options now as quickly as possible.

Comment: Good luck with that! Sounds like something that should be done with a throwaway PHP script, but it's not exactly trivial. I think there are already some questions about "create bundle products programmatically" that might help you.